# Pool capacity not reducing on event AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I would like the capacity of a resource pool to go from 2 to 1 at a specific point in time. As of now, I am using an event to trigger a reduction in a variable. This variable is what I use to define as the resource pool capacity so logically I would think that the resource pool capacity would drop as well. However, when the event triggers, the variable reduces but the resource pool capacity does not, even if the resources are idle and have no tasks.

Comment: Please show the code. Do you use myResource.set_capacity(5)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resource Pool capacity is not dynamic, so if you set it as a variable, the variable will only be accessed on model start-up. Changing the variable value during model runtime will not make a difference.

To change the capacity you need to use:

```
resourcePool.set_capacity(value);
```

Replace `value` with the variable name you are using.

For your information, fields preceded by an equal sign are static while those preceded with a circular arrow are dynamic. The example below shows both:

[image]

Comment: Setting resourcePool.set_capacity(value); in Capacity of my resource pool returns Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to int. I changed resourcePool to the name of the resource pool and value to the name of the variable

Comment: Not in capacity. You need to write that code in the event where you are updating your variable. So instead of changing your variable value only, add a line as I showed.

Comment: Again, what you put next to an equal sign, is only evaluated at model startup... So just write your initial capacity there, then whenever you need to change it, it will be a code in the action of the event you trigger.